# Search without special characters in vuetify data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, special-characters, v-data-table

I use the Vuetify data-table component, and I want to ignore special characters when I make a search.
For example in my table I have the polish name "Łukasz", and I want to found it when I type "lukasz".
Is it possible ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:
In my object, I add a value who concatenate the original Name and the name without special chars using [latinize.js](https://github.com/dundalek/latinize) module:

```js
import latinize from 'latinize';
Person.searchLastName = Person.LastName + ' ' + latinize(Person.LastName);
```

In the headers object, I use my new value, but I add a template to replace this content by original value like that:

```html
<template #[`item.Person.searchLastName`]="{ item }">
  <!-- use different value to allow search without special chars -->
  {{item.Person.LastName}}
</template>
```